# Does the damage from dragon breath attacks fall off with range?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have gone where I ought not and am now paying the price.  A dragon far above my level has landed and is attempting to breathe me to death.

My usual tactic of hiding behind trees has failed me.  My only hope is to double-fist fireballs and healing, and try to be where the damage isn't.  In most games, this means range.

**Does the damage from dragon breath attacks fall off with range?**

Comment: Don't forget to get your timing down too, so that your fireball pounds him right before he's about to do his breath attack. This of course will stop him in his tracks and save you from taking damage. Then just do your best to maintain your distance so he doesn't make a bite-sized morsel out of you! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are within the range of the breath attack, meaning from the dragons mouth to the edge of the cone, you will take the same amount of damage. The only way to take less damage is to not be within the breaths range, meaning you are not being hit and thus take no damage.